# How to insert parent and child in a OneToOne unidirectional relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm starting a Web application, and I have the following structure:

```
+--------------------------+
| Company                  |
|--------------------------|
| id            PK, NN, AI |
| attibute1                |
| attribute2               |
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
| CompanyProfile           |
|--------------------------|
| id            PK, NN, AI |
| id_company    FK, NN     |
| attribute3               |
| attribute4               |
| attribute5               |
+--------------------------+
```

---

```
 public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String attribute1;

    private String attribute2;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_company", unique = true)
    private CompanyProfile companyProfile;

    // ...
}
```

---

```
public class CompanyProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String attribute3;

    private String attribute4;

    private String attribute5;

    // ...
}
```

I'm sending a POST request to one controller with the following JSON:

```
{
    "attribute1": "value 1",
    "attribute2": "value 2",
    "companyProfile": {
        "attribute3": "value 3",
        "attribute4": "value 4",
        "attribute5": "value 5"
    }
}
```

So now I want to execute the command `.save()` and have the application to insert the company in its respectively table and after that, insert the `companyProfile` in its respective table, all at once. But that's not happening and I'm getting this: `Error Code: 1364. Field 'id_company' doesn't have a default value`.

What may I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Your mapping tells JPA that there is a id_company column in the *company* table, referring to the ID in the *companyprofile* table.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct. You will need to move that column to the correct table.

Comment: It didn't work either, could you post an example ?

Answer (score 0):

For your persistence, I think you will have to persist in the order below,

Persist Company object, then

Set the Company object into CompanyProfile and

Finally persist CompanyProfile